# How to implement change email functionality in Meteor.js

Tags: email, meteor

I want to implement change email functionality for my application built on Meteor.js

The flow would be:

1.User would request for change email via "Change Email" form.

```
    <div class="settings-container">
        <div class="container-header medium-margin-top bold">Change Email</div>
        <div class="container-inner less-margin-top">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <dl>
                        <dt><label for="user_email_address">Email Address</label></dt>
                        <dd><input type="email" class="form-control" id="new-email"></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="btn-change-email" class="btn btn-success">Send Verification Link</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2.The forms sends a verification email using Accounts.sendVerificationEmail

I created a method for the same which is called when the verification mail needs to be sent

```
change_email: function(userId, email) {
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, email);
},
```

3.The email address should change once the user verifies the new email address.

I am unable to think of a proper solution for step three. I thought of using **Accounts.verifyEmail** but could not think out a way to change the email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're going about it backwards. You should first add the new email to the `Meteor.user.emails` array, or replace the existing entry if you really want to update rather than use the built-in support for multiple email addresses. Then you can send the verification email.